# как сделать из списка int

Tags: python

```
v = [10,20,30]

# а надо чтобы

v = 102030 # и типа данных int
```

Comment: `int(''.join(map(str, v)))` p.s. Чтобы ответить более содержательно, нужны дополнительные вводные. Например, насколько большой список? Какой тип данных внутри? Какие крайние случаи ожидаются?

Answer (score 0):

Сперва пройдись по списку классическим способом:

```
for i in v:
   a = "".join(str(i))
```

а затем преобразуй всё это в целое число:

```
a = int(a)
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).